# How can I reload the page after a Panels IPE save?

Tags: panels

I've seen it posted about a few times on drupal.org but no implementation.. Panels IPE breaks a few things like javascript and custom views footers until the page is reloaded.

I'd like to have this reload happen automatically as site users are allowed to use IPE.